# Using click EventListener to change active tabs, how do i add a default active tab when reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make active tabs that show content depending on which tab you click.
I absolutely need the first tab to be active by default so i put the "active" class manually in the HTML so the base content is shown.

The issue is, i do that through an empty variable to hold the state but after you've already clicked once. Here is the code :

```js
function homeLoaded() {
    menuLoaded();
    function menuLoaded() {
        const sideMenuChildren = document.getElementById("sidemenu").childNodes;
        let currentTab;
        for(let i = 0; i < sideMenuChildren.length; i++) {
            const tab = sideMenuChildren[i];
            tab.addEventListener(
                "click",
                function() {
                    if(currentTab) {
                        sideMenuChildren[currentTab].classList.remove("liactive");
                    }
                    currentTab = i;
                    sideMenuChildren[currentTab].classList.add("liactive");
                    showContent(tab.id);
                    console.log("I clicked " + i);
                }
            );
        }
    }

    let currentPage;
    function showContent(menuName) {
        const pageContainer = document.getElementById("content");
        const element = pageContainer.querySelector("." + menuName);
        if(currentPage) {
            currentPage.classList.remove("selected");
        }
        currentPage = element;

        element.classList.add("selected");
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```html
<div id="main" style="background-image: url(./images/bg2.png);">
    <div id="box">

        <ul id="sidemenu">
            <li id="profil" class="liactive">Profil</li>
            <li id="parcours">Parcours</li> 
            <li id="contact">Contact</li> 
        </ul>
        
        <div id="content">
            <div class="profil selected"><p>Blabla</p></div>
            <div class="parcours"><p>Blablabla</p></div>
            <div class="contact"><p>Blablablabla</p></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="bottomnav">
            <div id="bottomnavcontent">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What this does sadly is that when i click another tab...it does not remove the first active tab, so i have 2 active tabs until i re-click the first tab to store it in the variable. I don't know how to fix this.

[image: Here is a picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo of working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCfZK.gif)You can get event inside the event listener function. There you can get the target.
So,first Remove active class of current tab. Then, set active class for target element.
i.e

```
tab.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (ev) {
          const currentab = document.querySelector(".liactive");
        
          currentab.classList.remove("liactive")
          ev.target.classList.add("liactive")
        
        }
      )
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for the tip, i tried using it but it didn't work for my case sadly. I updated my initial post with the HTML. Have a good day!

Comment: Hey, I tried your code with my suggestion. It worked for me.

Comment: Oh i must be formatting the code wrong, i'm sorry, would you mind please posting your entire code if that's not an issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated code in answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Great...Welcome